# cron expression to run a webjob at 1 am, day 1 of august every year in azure

Tags: azure

cron expression to run a webjob at 1 am, day 1 of august every year in azure
Example : 
            1st Aug, 2020 01:00 AM
Next run at 1st Aug, 2021 01:00 AM

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The example schedule cron should be `0 0 1 1 8 *`.